# select a list of objects in praat

Tags: praat

I have a list of objects from a for loop and I would like to append them to a list so that I can select and concatenate them.  My idea is that the code would function more or less like this:

```
for stringNumber from 0 to numberOfStrings
    do string stuff...


    tgID = Create TextGrid: tmin, tmax, tier_name$, phone$
    Set interval text: 1, 1, phone$
    # THIS IS WHERE I NEED HELP
    tgList = append: tgID + ", " 

endfor

selectObject: tgList
do ("Concatenate")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try this:

```
for stringNumber from 0 to numberOfStrings
    # do string stuff...

    tgID = Create TextGrid: tmin, tmax, tier_name$, phone$
    Set interval text: 1, 1, phone$

    tgList[stringNumber + 1] = tgID
endfor

selectObject()

for i from 1 to numberOfStrings + 1
    plusObject: tgList[i]
endfor

Concatenate
```

`selectObject()` deselects everything, then `plusObject` adds the current object to the selection. I am not sure the loop indexes are correct in the selection loop, because you start your loop from 0, and I cannot try your code.

Comment: That was the key with plusObject and selectObject.  Thanks!

Comment: +1 for `selectObject()`. Until now, I had been doing `nocheck selectObject: undefined`, which is much more cryptic... and a lot longer.

Answer (score 0):

It might be overkill in this particular case, but you could also use the [`selection`](http://cpran.net/plugins/selection) plugin, available on CPrAN, which was created to manage object selections (full disclosure: I wrote it):

```
include ../../plugin_selection/procedures/tables.proc

@createEmptySelectionTable()
selection = createEmptySelectionTable.table

for stringNumber from 0 to numberOfStrings
    Create TextGrid: tmin, tmax, tier_name$, phone$
    Set interval text: 1, 1, phone$
    @addToSelectionTable: selection
endfor   

@restoreSavedSelection: selection 
removeObject: selection
Concatenate
```

For this to work, however, you'd need your script to be in a sub-directory within a plugin (so somewhere like `~/.praat-dir/plugin_foo/scripts/here.praat` in Linux / Mac).

Hopefully in the future there will be a way around this. Then again, most Praat scripts really should be in plugins, even if they are project specific, so... `</rant>`